# Delimiting Character

Tags: sas, statistics

We are loading a Fixed width text file into a SAS dataset.

The character we are using to delimit multi valued field values is being interpreted as 2 characters by SAS. This breaks things, because the fields are of a fixed width.

We can use characters that appear on the keyboard, but obviously this isn't as safe, because our data could actually contain those characters.

The character we would like to use is '§'.

I'm guessing this may be an encoding issue, but don't know what to do about it.

Comment: I've been able to use '§' as a delimiter just fine so I'm guessing my infile is not set up quite like yours.  If you could add an example row or two it might help us clue in to a solution faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you use the keycode for the character like DLM='09'x and change 09 to the right keycode?

Comment: Should be A7, as in

DLM='A7'x